# matching everything until the next match

Tags: regex

I want to match an html code until next appearance of ... or end.

Currently I have the following regex:

```
(<font color=\"#777777\">\.\.\. .+?<\/font>)
```

Which will match just that:

```
1. <font color="#777777">... </font><font color="#000000">lives up to the customer's expectations. The subscriber is </font>
2. <font color="#777777">... You may not want them to be </font>
3. <font color="#777777">... </font><font color="#000000">the web link, and </font>
```

But I would want:

```
1. <font color="#777777">... </font><font color="#000000">lives up to the customer's expectations. The subscriber is </font><font color="#777777">obviously thinking about your merchandise </font><font color="#000000">in case they have clicked about the link in your email.</font>
2. <font color="#777777">... You may not want them to be </font><font color="#000000">disappointed by simply clicking </font>
3. <font color="#777777">... </font><font color="#000000">the web link, and </font><font color="#777777">finding </font><font color="#000000">the page to </font><font color="#777777">get other than </font><font color="#000000">what they thought it </font><font color="#777777">will be.. If America makes</font>
```

Here is the html that I want to parse:

```
<font color="#777777">... </font><font color="#000000">lives up to the customer's expectations. The subscriber is </font><font color="#777777">obviously thinking about your merchandise  </font><font color="#000000">in case they have clicked about the link in your email.</font><font color="#777777">... You may not want them to be </font><font color="#000000">disappointed by simply clicking </font><font color="#777777">... </font><font color="#000000">the web link, and </font><font color="#777777">finding  </font><font color="#000000">the page to </font><font color="#777777">get other than  </font><font color="#000000">what they thought it </font><font color="#777777">will be.. If America makes</font>
```

And demonstration:
http://rubular.com/r/mmQ4TBZb96

How to match all texts starting with ... ... to get the desired matches above?

Thanks for help!

Comment: question poorly phrased. When you say all strings, do you mean strings within the __font__ tags? What kind of output do you expect

Comment: What is your expected match output?

Comment: are you trying to join the phrases?

Comment: Use `.*?` instead of `.+?`.

Comment: Hey, I edited the question. Please see the example what I want to match. The .*? instead of .+? won't help

Comment: It may be wiser efficient to use a xml/html parser, because it's easier and less error prone than regexes

Comment: Why is "finding" matched when everywhere else you are talking about matching 3 dots?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo.. I edited it

Comment: can you just use [this link i make](http://regexr.com?35f9h) as your parser? the bottom big panel is exactly the same as your wanted text. if you want to parse another text just place it on the top panel.

Answer (score 2):

Even though your question seems inconsistent (I don't understand why you would get the final desired match), I think this is what you're after:

```
((<font color=\"#777777\">\.{3}) .+?(<\/font>(?=\s*\2)|$))
```

It uses a look-ahead to make the end of the match be just *before* the next "..." sequence (or end of input.

See [this on rubular](http://rubular.com/r/J0fyAwPYgk)

Comment: Hey, this is what I'm looking for, but it won't find the last match (just two of them)

Comment: This looks alright, though Rubular doesn't get it right (it shows me only the first match), at the link from Angga above it's correct.

Comment: When I run it in ruby, I get the same output as with rubular - without the last match. Do you have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: @Armali OK - I've fixed it, and simplified it a little too. Rubular link updated too

Comment: @Aljaz OK - I've fixed it, and simplified it a little too by recycling the initial text as a back reference in the look ahead. The problem was obvious in the end - the text had a `<br>` at the end I didn't notice, so the look-ahead had to *exclude* that. Rubular link updated too

Answer (score 0):

The question is about regexp, but you could also do it in the following way (Perl syntax, but I believe this kind of functions exist in other languages too):

```
split(/(?=<font color=\"#777777\">\.\.\.)/, $your_text)
```

Comment: this will only match the content in the font tag, not the content after the tag

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand the question. The answer by @Bohemian looks great (I couldn't have done it better), but since I had already posted an answer I need to provide alternative approach.